# ASP .Net Core Routing - Unable to determine why GET with parameters cannot be routed to

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing

I've being trying to get a simple parameter GET working however it keeps routing to the parameter-less GET. When I remove the parameter-less GET it simply is unable to find it and gives me a 404.

I've tried different variations of the Routing Attributes and HttpGet attributes all to no avail. I have a feeling I'm missing something simple here.

Controller

```
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    public class ModelController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDataRepository _repository;
        private readonly ILogger<VehicleController> _logger;

        public ModelController(IDataRepository repository, ILogger<VehicleController> logger)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(_repository.GetAllModels());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Failed to get models : {ex}");
                return BadRequest("Failed to get models");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("{id:Guid}")]
        public IActionResult GetAllModelsById(Guid id)
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(_repository.GetModelsByMaker(id));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Failed to get models for maker : {ex}");
                return BadRequest("Failed to get models for maker");
            }
        }
    }
```

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(cfg =>
            cfg.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("WebAppConnectionString")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddTransient<DataSeeder>();
            services.AddScoped<IDataRepository, DataRepository>();
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });

            //app.UseEndpoints(x => x.MapControllers());
        }
```

Comment: what URL are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

In AspNetCore 3.0 we can use static and dynamic routing. Dynamic routing seems to be not our cases

In static routing we can choose 2 different approaches.

> **First approaches is hard-coded manually typed routes.**

For example, if we want to show our about page in the begging of the application, **we should use route variations like in the code below in controller**. This variations of routes contains http://localhost:5000 or http://localhost:5000/about, all url will route about controller's index action.

**Your About Controller settings seems to configured use something like this apporach.**

```
   [Route("")]
   [Route("About")]
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
```

> **Second approach is centralized routes in startup**

**You should tell to application, which route pattern will using when start app**.

Well this is quite easy and you should see when the create new asp.net core mvc application.

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Nice! we say, use this pattern in url

**"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"**

Let me explain to you;

- First coming controller name which default is Home
  ({controller=Home})
- And then coming (/) action name which default value is
  Index({action=Index})
- And then coming(/) parameters id and this can be
  null(optional)({id?})

**Default values mean, when we don't write something on url, which route application will use.** In default route we use home/index url and route, this means if we hit http://localhost:5000 only, we get home/index action.

In this cases your problem should solve, choose one of them these approaches.